# Manipulate curves

Tags: plotting, manipulate, evaluation, attributes

I want to draw curves with manipulation.
When I use the following code, I receive nothing.

```
a = Table[
   E^(-(\[Pi]^2/
     2) (delta^2 Q^4 + 2 q0^2 (Q^3 - defocus Q)^2)), {defocus, 1, 4, 
    1}];
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[a], {Q, 0, 3}], {{q0, .05}, {.05, .1}}, {{delta, 
   0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}}]
```

But if I write explicitly the variable "a", I do receive what I need.

I've check the attributes of Manipulate, which has HoldAll.
I don't know if it's related to this.

Could you please explain to me why it's like this ?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Manipulate needs to "see" the parameters in the definition of `a` explicitly in order to be able to change them; move the definition of a inside the `Manipulate`: `Manipulate[a=(*your code*); Plot[(*your code*)],...]`.

Comment: See also the docs of Manipulate, in the ["Possible Issues" section](http://wolfram.com/xid/0ftsp6s-hms7): "Manipulate only "notices" explicit visible parameters".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a scoping issue. Make the arguments to `a` explicit.

```
Clear[a]

a[Q_, q0_, delta_] =
  Table[
   E^(-(π^2/2) (delta^2 Q^4 + 2 q0^2 (Q^3 - defocus Q)^2)),
   {defocus, 1, 4, 1}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  Evaluate[a[Q, q0, delta]],
  {Q, 0, 3},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic],
 {{q0, .05}, {.05, .1}},
 {{delta, .1}, {.1, .2}}]
```

[image]